# What's this character that looks like 七 with a ～ in the middle? And what's its history?

Tags: meaning, character-identification, glyph-origin

Having a hard time figuring out what this guy is:

[image: hahaha]

The equivalent Wikisource page for the material I'm working with says that it is:

> 甚

Perhaps it is

[image: yes?]

Which [zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=000302) says it is:

> 同【甚】字。

If it is `七 + 丶 + 丶`, where did this character come from?

(It's a pain to search, the character isn't even encoded into Unicode)

Was it shorthand or did it have another history?

Comment: There are a lot of  characters like that, just a variation, 异体字.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character [image] is recorded in the following titles:

- 《漢簡文字類編．甘部》
- 《中華字海．一部》

The paleographer 季旭昇 analyses it to be a 草書 variant of「甚」.

See the [entry of 甚 from the Taiwan Ministry of Education's variants dictionary](http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAyNjIx).

---

The earliest form of「甚」compounds「匕」(*a ladle or spoon*) with either「甘」or「口」:

[image]

> Note: the difference between「甘」and「口」in this context doesn't make a big
>   difference, as「甘」(*sweet*) was originally「口」with a mark, representing a piece of food in a mouth:
>
> [image]
>
> The meaning of *sweet/good flavours* is extracted from the idea of tasting the food.

The entire compound form of「甚」meant *contentment, happiness, at peace*, as a result of being satisfied from being fed.

Later on, decorative marks (飾筆)** were added on to the character, in the shape of「八」:

[image]

Since characters weren't standardised back then, sometimes「口」and「八」were switched around:

[image]

This last form is the direct ancestor of the modern form of「甚」.

> Note: The Shuowen Jiezi explanation of「甚」comes from the misinterpretation of 「八」and「匕」as merging into「匹」:
>
> **「甚，尤安樂也。从甘，从匹耦也。」**

Of course, the above doesn't explain the cursive form that appears in the question. ***My personal speculation*** is that [image] is a result of (1) character corruption (訛變) and (2) character simplification (簡化/省略).

**(1) Corruption**

> 「匕」was commonly corrupted into「七」or「」very early on, as in the
>   Eastern Han stele 《曹全碑》:
>
> [image]
>
> What looks like「合**七**首藥神明膏」should be interpreted
>   as「合**匕**首藥神明膏」(*miraculous knife-wound-healing medicine*),
>   where「匕首」means *dagger*. Many modern forms have retained this
>   corruption, such as in the character「化」, which was originally「⿰亻匕」.
>   See, for example, the modern Chinese (left) form vs. the modern
>   Japanese (right) form of 「化」:
>
> [image][image]

**(2) Simplification**

> 「口」was simply omitted from the final form in rapid 草書 writing.

Of course, take all this with a grain of salt; I haven't found a detailed academic commentary on the character [image], and welcome any corrections to this answer by anyone who has.

---

**The addition of *decorative marks* is one of the least-known, at least among general knowledge, of Chinese character components. One of the most common characters which was formed as a result of decorative marks is the character「魚」. Compare, for example, some of the earliest forms of the character:

1. A detailed drawing of a fish in oracle bone script:
   [image]
2. Still quite detailed in the middle of the bronze inscription period:
   [image]
3. Sometimes, not so detailed and more stylised:
   [image]
4. Stylised with addition of decorative marks around the tail:
   [image]

The shape of the bottom looked very similar to and was later merged with the shape of「火」, eventually turning into「灬」and causing the tail to be detached to the rest of the body. This latter form can be considered as the direct ancestor of the modern form of「魚」:
[image]

If these marks weren't added, we might see something like this today:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use links with generic names such as "this" or "here, because if the site goes offline or the link breaks, then it will become useless. Add some context from the link so that even if something goes wrong, other users can have some context.

Comment: @Alenanno I've actually summarised all the information that was relevant to the question. There wasn't much information on the page, but I'll edit the answer to include the organisation's name.

Comment: Thank you. Mine was general advice, you know how to give proper context since it's your answer, but this way a future visitor might find the answer even if the link breaks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the character 正. 行书或草书的[正](https://m.baidu.com/sf/lj?ext=%7B%22url%22%3A%22%2Ffrom%3D1086k%2Fbd_page_type%3D1%2Fssid%3D0%2Fuid%3D0%2Fpu%3Dusm%25402%252Csz%2540320_1001%252Cta%2540iphone_2_7.0_3_537%2Fbaiduid%3D6CC8030E70C4F4D46B07D66AAFB84FEC%2Fw%3D0_10_%2Ft%3Diphone%2Fl%3D3%2Ftc%3Fref%3Dwww_iphone%26lid%3D11384531760824639920%26order%3D1%26fm%3Dalop%26waplogo%3D1%26h5ad%3D1%26srd%3D1%26dict%3D32%26tj%3Dwww_normal_1_0_10_title%26vit%3Dosres%26waput%3D4%26cltj%3Dnormal_title%26asres%3D1%26nt%3Dwnor%26title%3D%25E6%25AD%25A3%25E5%25AD%2597%25E7%259A%2584%25E4%25B9%25A6%25E6%25B3%2595%25E5%2586%2599%25E6%25B3%2595_%25E6%25AD%25A3%25E5%25AD%2597%25E6%2580%258E%25E4%25B9%2588%25E5%2586%2599_%25E6%25AD%25A3%25E5%25AD%2597%25E7%259A%2584%25E5%2590%2584%25E7%25A7%258D%25E5%2586%2599%25E6%25B3%2595...-%25E4%25B9%25A6%25E6%25B3%2595%25E7%2588%25B1%25E7%25BD%2591%26w_qd%3DIlPT2AEptyoA_ykz9QEc-hO5IixTe7QoxjkZfAXV6A3%26tcplug%3D1%26sec%3D26915%26di%3D58709ed8d035ef55%26bdenc%3D1%26tch%3D124.210.243.364.1.0%26nsrc%3DIlPT2AEptyoA_yixCFOxXnANedT62v3IGtiCLTlS1ze895qshbWxBdUfEFXpKXuPIkewdoSYeAoDljrzOjh6hhZ1rqw0snN8nyC-%26eqid%3D9dfdfb51921ae000100000025a5c8d41%26wd%3D%26clk_info%3D%257B%2522srcid%2522%253A1599%252C%2522tplname%2522%253A%2522www_normal%2522%252C%2522t%2522%253A1516014931029%252C%2522xpath%2522%253A%2522div-a-h3%2522%257D%22%2C%22frame_only%22%3A1%2C%22lid%22%3A%2211384531760824639920%22%7D&pd=mms_mip&actname=introduction&ms=1&title=%E6%AD%A3%E5%AD%97%E8%8D%89%E4%B9%A6%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E5%86%99)就这么写。better you have a context to figure out. Otherwise, it is very hard. It might also be like Japanese.

It could also be 甚 as you said.

[image]